# SVN integration and bugtraq property

Tags: intellij-idea

[Tortoisesvn](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) and Subclipse have support for `bugtraq` property. This is really nice, because on check-in you can provide JIRA case id.

Is it also supported by SVN integration of IntelliJ?

Comment: No: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-4549

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not directly supported, we usually provide issue id from our JIRA as a first part of the commit message. Also we start feature branch names with issue ID.

Eg:

> PROJECTID-1234 Some commit message

Comment: I think this is the right format: JIRA PROJECTID-1234: Some commit message